# BeautifulSoup not returning expected results

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape the [nba player data off ESPN](http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20161217) and i'm running into a problem where when i run this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20161217")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

game_Id = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "events"})    
print(game_Id)
```

which should return a list of the html code corresponding to the games that were played that day, but it gives me an empty array. anyone know why?

Comment: The ID `events` is not rendered in the HTML content of the page when the DOM is first created. If you view the page source you will see that the `#events` is empty. Though you can look into it closely if the data is loaded through AJAX or is added to the `#events` after the DOM is ready.

Comment: Last time I checked,  scraping ESPN was against their terms of service

Comment: BeautifulSoup will not work here, you will need to use Selenium or something

Answer (score 0):

In the html returned from "http://www.espn.com/nba/scoreboard/_/date/20161217", the element you speak of appears empty: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9Dk.jpg.